# Connection of two simultaneous C programs

Tags: c

I have to know about how to connect the inputs and outputs of two simple running C program simultaneously by interfacing a third Java/C program in between.

I had tried by piping, socket and clients connection but it could not be helpful for a simple running C program where only scanf() and printf() is used

Sample programs:
Program1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int a;
  while(1)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Program2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int a;
  while(1)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My aim is to connect stdin and stdout of program1.c with stdin and stdout of program2.c with the help of a third Java or C program

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you'll want to do something like this:

- “Program3” creates a `pipe`
- Program 3 calls `fork`, and in the child, changes out the `pipe`'s FD for `stdout`, then `exec`'s Program2;
- Program 3 then changes out the `pipe` for `stdin`, and `exec`'s Program1

Comment: Yes sir/mam i want to do something like this only I want to get the outline of the code to be used in case of Java/C

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fork` and `exec`
Write a third C program, which would open a two pipes (using `pipe`). This gives you 4 file descriptors (2 input, 2 output).
Then it forks - the child will later run program1 and the parent program2 (or vice versa - doesn't matter).
Each of the children will close 2 file descriptors, and remain with one input and one output (but not of the same pipe). They should also close standard input and output.
Then use the `dup2` function to make the pipe fds become 0 and 1.
Now you have two processes, with one's stdin connected by pipe to the other's stdout, and vice versa.
The last stage is to use `exec` to make the run `program1` and `program2`.

Comment: I want to get the sample of third program for connecting two programs. I am not able to get the program code to run two programs simultaneously.